# Using a Text Widget on the "trailing" property is not shown in the GridTileBar Widget but the Icon Widget is does

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-layout

**Hello Everyone!**

Here I am working on a small project which is a gallery application, I managed to display the album along with its thumbnail.

I also want to display the name and total files of the album that I have got from my local gallery with the `GridTileBar` which the album name is on the left and the total files are on the right,

for my left I managed to display the album name using the `title` property but, for the right one which is the total file, I can't display it using the `trailing` property and strangely when I try to display the `Icon` Widget, the icon appears and is right beside the album name that I have displayed.

**Result from `flutter doctor`**

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.22.5, on Linux, locale en_US.UTF-8)
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.3)
[!] Android Studio (not installed)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)

! Doctor found issues in 1 category.
```

**Tools**

```
Debugging on My actual device which is Xiaomi Redmi 1S Android 7.1 Nougat
```

**Expectation**

[image: expectation]

**Reality**

[image: reality]

**Code `album_card.dart`**

```dart
import 'dart:io';

import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class AlbumCard extends StatelessWidget {
  AlbumCard(
      {@required this.albumName, this.thumbnail, this.totalFiles, this.isOdd});

  final String albumName;
  final int totalFiles;
  final File thumbnail;
  final bool isOdd;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(0),
        clipBehavior: Clip.antiAliasWithSaveLayer,
        child: GridTile(
          child: Image.file(
            thumbnail,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
          ),
          footer: GridTileBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.black45,
            title: Text('$albumName'),

            // Won't work if displaying a Text Widget but Work if it's an Icon Widget
            trailing: Text('$totalFiles'),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **maxLines** property of Text widget to show full text if necessary.
Take a look at the example below:

```
GridTile(
      child: Image.network(
        imageUrl,
        fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
      footer: GridTileBar(
        backgroundColor: Colors.black54,
        leading: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(Icons.favorite),
          onPressed: () {},
          iconSize: 20,
        ),
        title: Text(
          title,
          textAlign: TextAlign.center,
          style: TextStyle(fontSize: 14),
          maxLines: 2, // will show max two lines of text
        ),
        trailing: IconButton(
          icon: Icon(
            Icons.shopping_cart,
          ),
          iconSize: 20,
          onPressed: () {},
        ),
      ),
    );
```